# How to run DeleteItemRequest on dynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, delete-row

When I am running a DeleteItemRequest on a dynamoDB table, I am getting an exception which says "the provided key size doesn't match with that of the schema". 
All I am doing is

`DeleteItemRequest deleteRequest = new` `DeleteItemRequest().withTableName(dynamoDbTableName).withKey(key);`

`client.deleteItem(deleteRequest);`

Do I need to specify something more? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

It could mean that the key passed to the method does not match the type of the primary key in the table. For example, you are passing a numerical key but the table uses a string key. The type of the key depends on the method used when creating the AttributeValue. The method `withN()` creates a numerical key, while the method `.withS()` creates a string key.

Numerical key example:

```
Key key = new Key().withHashKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withN("120"));
```

String key example:

```
Key key = new Key().withHashKeyElement(new AttributeValue().withS("johndoe"));
```

There are methods for other types as well, like binary types and sets. See the [javadoc for the AttributeValue class](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/AttributeValue.html) for more details.